# Monitor keeps waking up to check signal

Tags: display

I have an LG 22ea63 monitor and whenever I turn off my pc and the monitor it stays off for a short while and then suddenly turns itself on to display "checking for signal" then  it concludes there's no signal and displays the no signal screen for the dvi port. Then it goes into standby. This is an annoyance when I try to sleep.

Anything I can do that doesn't include removing power supply whenever I turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small thought have you went through your monitor settings ? Make sure it's set to high performance and disable sleep mode if present .

Very highly unlikely in some certain cases you need to install the monitor driver or update it .